# Fast way to split primary key into ranges

Tags: sql-server

I want to split values of an auto-incrementing primary key into ranges of approximately equal size as fast as possible. The number of ranges is low, less than 20. So far I've came up with this:

Determine approximate row count by querying `sys.partitions` and calculate bucket size.

Run a query `select min(id), max(id) from (select top 1000000 id from my_table order by id desc) t`

Run a series of queries

```
select min(id), max(id)
from (
    select top 1000000 id
    from my_table where id > $prev_max
    order by id desc) t;
```

until all the ranges are found.

Query times are acceptable (several seconds for the first one and less than second for subsequent queries) but is there an easier (preferably a single query) way? Generated ranges don't need to be exact, it's ok if they intersect or have gaps, I just need a good enough estimate.

Comment: What are you trying to use these range estimates for?

Comment: @KirkSaunders dumping table in parallel.

Comment: [`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(PrimaryKey)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener It's impossible to pass the number of buckets to `SHOW STATISTICS` and bucket sizes are really uneven for the tables I'm interested in.

Comment: They're only uneven if you don't aggregate them.  If you are using SQL 2016 SP1 CU2 or later you can always tap into them via the [`sys.dm_db_stats_histogram`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-histogram-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) DMF.  Just listing it as another option as tapping into histograms will be fast regardless the size of the table in question.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener `dm_db_stats_histogram` shows essentially the same thing `DBCC SHOW STATISTIC`.

Comment: Correct, with the main distinctive difference being you can query that DMF via TSQL (without CLR), unlike `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS()`.

Comment: Your requirement is exactly similar to paging.Where you find TotalRecord,divide them in Range according to pagesize(bucket size),then view record by passing Pageindex. Is this your requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NTILE and a CTE to produce a specified number of buckets of roughly equal size from your table. Example below with ~590,000 rows takes 1 second to run the query.

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE RangeQuery (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Val INT)
GO

INSERT INTO RangeQuery (Val)
SELECT 1
GO 590000

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RangeQuery
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, NTILE(20) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS [Range]
    FROM RangeQuery
)

SELECT [Range] AS [Bucket],
    MIN(ID) AS FirstID, 
    MAX(ID) AS LastID, 
    COUNT(ID) AS [RowCount]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Range]
```

Results:

```
Bucket  FirstID     LastID      RowCount
----------------------------------------
1       1           29919       29919
2       29920       59838       29919
3       59839       89757       29919
4       89758       119676      29919
5       119677      149595      29919
6       149596      179513      29918
7       179514      209431      29918
8       209432      239349      29918
9       239350      269267      29918
10      269268      299185      29918
11      299186      329103      29918
12      329104      359021      29918
13      359022      388939      29918
14      388940      418857      29918
15      418858      448775      29918
16      448776      478693      29918
17      478694      508611      29918
18      508612      538529      29918
19      538530      568447      29918
20      568448      598365      29918
```

Comment: I'm interested in tables with billions of rows, and this query is pretty slow on such tables

Comment: @synapse You need to better define what you're actually doing with the output, and maybe there will be better ideas. Reading billions of rows is just not fast, sorry.